# Consulta SQL PgAdmin 4

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, pgadmin

> Listar los productos y sus categorías excluyendo a los productos mas caros y mas baratos por categoría*/

Esto es lo que he realizado

```
select  pr.prod_nombre,
        ca.cate_nombre,
        pr.prod_precio
from Empresa.producto as pr,
     Empresa.categoria as ca
where pr.cate_id=ca.cate_id
group by    pr.prod_precio,
            pr.prod_nombre,
            ca.cate_nombre
having pr.prod_precio=max(pr.prod_precio)
union
select pr.prod_nombre,ca.cate_nombre,pr.prod_precio
from Empresa.producto as pr,Empresa.categoria as ca
where pr.cate_id=ca.cate_id
group by pr.prod_precio,pr.prod_nombre,ca.cate_nombre
having pr.prod_precio=min(pr.prod_precio)
```

Y por ahora me da el siguiente resultado

```
nombre de producto---- nombre de categoria---- precio de producto 

pr.prod_nombre.................ca.cate_nombre.........pr.prod_precio

Perro caliente.................comida rapida...............$2.500

hamburguesa....................comida rapida...............$2.500

jabon..........................producto de aseo............$1.500

martillo........................heramienta.................$5.000
```

Comment: ¿Esta otra pregunta no es la misma? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/393345/base-de-datos-consulta-sql

Answer (score 0):

Como consejo general te digo que uses la **cláusula inner join** y en la **cláusula having** pon:

```
having 
pr.prod_precio between min(pr.prod_precio) and max(pr.prod_precio)
```

El **operador union** no hace falta, prueba esto y mantenme informado.

El **operador between** se usa para ver los valores que están entre dos números.

Otra forma de hacerlo es poner:

```
having
pr.prod_precio > min(pr.prod_precio) and pr.prod_precio < max(pr.prod_precio)
```